# Real analysis help needed.

Tags: real-analysis

Does anyone knows how to prove this:

Given $\{\epsilon_k\}$,  an  arbitrary sequence with elements $+1$ and $-1$,
prove that $\sum\epsilon_k 2^{-n_k }$ is an irrational number if and only if $\limsup (n_{k+1}-n_k)=\infty$.

Thanks.

Comment: Use \infty to get $\infty$

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that "if and only if" is true.  If the gaps have bounded length, but are distributed randomly...that comes to a rational number?   Interesting.  That's not true if, say, you replace $2$ by $10$....but doesn't the usual argument about rationality and periodicity work just as well in base $2$?